# refresh div on success jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would simply like to refresh the content of the div on success. The content inside the div is a php code which retrieves records from the database. I tried the below but the div just disappears and nothing is being refreshed. Can someone help me out?

```
<div class="div_wrap">
<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from inbox where username = ? and id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $id);//the vars are already defined.
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo $row['message'];
echo $row['date'];
}
?>
</div>

<script>
var dataString = 'message='+ message + '&subject='+ subject;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "message.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#errormsg").html('<div style="padding-left:120px;">Please wait<img src="image/loader.gif" alt="Loading...." align="absmiddle" title="Loading...."/></div><br clear="all">');

        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('.div_wrap').html(response);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use AJAX to fetch the data and place the new data in the DIV

Comment: You can't re-run serverside code on the client side. You'll need to either re-run it via AJAX or reload the page.

Comment: Can you add console.log(response) and tell us what the content of the response is?

Comment: Please include the portion of the code you took out. Is it an AJAX call?

Comment: @showdev updated the question with the code.

Comment: Can you log the content of response. If you're getting an empty response from your php script, the div will disappear since you would be basically updating the content with nothing.

Comment: @ReX357 where do I add that?

Comment: Inside the success block.

Comment: success: function(response) { console.log(response); }

Comment: @ReX357 I put it and nothing is showing up.

Comment: Nothing is showing up where? You've looked in the console of the browser correct?

Comment: @ReX357 Oops I thought it was gonna show up on the page. in console under logging tab it displays "" two double quotes.

Comment: OK so you're getting an empty response. OK so let's first make sure you're building your data string properly. Please add console.log(dataString); before the ajax block, right under var dataString = ... and tell me what you see in the console then. You can remove the console.log(response) line in the success block now.

Comment: @ReX357 "message=test&subject=hi"

Comment: OK so dataString is built properly. Please update your question with the content of message.php since we ruled out that javascript is the problem here.

Comment: That whole code snippet is the content of message.php? That's not gonna work.

Comment: First off how is this ajax getting called? Does it just executes once the page is loaded?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43468/discussion-between-rex357-and-user3006683)

Comment: @ReX357 Actually it is. I gave up and used `window.location.reload();` on success which refreshed the whole page. For the moment that is enough until I figure out the another way. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Not the effect you're looking for though with the full page reload. Basically your message.php should be a separate file dedicated to returning the ajax results to the page.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `div` should look like this:

```
<div class="div_wrap">

</div>
```

Then, for your ajax success function to load the content into the `div`, your php should return the **html** code it self, something like this:

```
echo "table><tr><td>Super content</td></tr></table>";
```